# Grab a response mid--transact_write_items in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

In boto3, I know transact_write_items is an atomic method. Let's say inside of my transact_write_items, I'm trying to delete from a table and update a table. For example:

1. Delete item from ITEM_TABLE
2. UPDATE entry in CHARACTER_TABLE, specifically removing item from a set

Is it possible to do this in a single transaction where, when I delete the item, it gives me the user_id Primary Key to find which entry in CHARACTER_TABLE to modify?

I know I can do this in separate calls, but in that case, it wouldn't be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're asking is not possible. You should read the item first to obtain the keys you need then for the transaction, which will still be atomic.

Comment: Thanks. I also don't currently see a way to batch delete entries inside a transact writie items. Is this feature not currently supported?

Comment: You can delete up to 100 items in a single transaction. Add up to 100 DeleteItem.